# lazy load plugin to load images as user scrolls?

Tags: jquery

I really like the lazy load plugin and I am gutted it's not working on new browsers.

Is there anyway I can write my own code that doesn't load the images below the fold until the user scrolls?

```
<img _src="/fullscreen/img/You are everywhere 2.png" class='lazyLoad' />

jQuery('.lazyLoad').each(function(){
       var _elm= jQuery(this);
       _elm.attr('src',_elm.attr('_src'));

       //on DOM ready loop through each 
      //image with class=lazyLoad and add src attribute to it.
})
```

It would be great if I can get this nailed, it's a pity [the appelsiini site](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html) isn't supported any longer.

I found a site that works in all browsers http://haw-lin.com/ and it's using a very similar plugin script to http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload. There's no MIT license and I find it difficult to decipher.

What jQuery image lazy load plugin can you recommend?

Comment: What browsers does it not work in?

Comment: the one on appelslini.net seems to work just fine for me in firefox and chrome and safari

Comment: Safari although it was my test that wasn't working and I was told it was a bug. Now I'm not so sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo page of [jQuery image lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) doesn't seem to work to me on FF3.6 on Mac. I was watching the HTTP requests with the Net tab of Firebug and I could see all the images loaded onload.

You can check out this plugin called [JAIL](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail) that works perfectly (requires some HTML changes though).
I especially suggest to look at the the examples.

Comment: Link for JAIL down. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [forks of jquery_lazyload in github](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/jquery_lazyload/network), some of them [address the issues](https://github.com/jney/jquery_lazyload/commits/master/) with [newer browsers](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/jquery_lazyload/commit/d481987d936cce2d777e7ce1a7f50090e348b7f1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jQuery plugin I wrote that uses HTML comments to lazy load any arbitrary bits of HTML, including images:

[jQuery Lazy Loader Blog Post](http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll/)

[jQuery Lazy Loader Plugin Page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LazyLoadOnScroll)

Here's an example:

```
<pre class=”i-am-lazy” ><!–
    <img src=”some.png” />
 –></pre>

<pre class=”i-am-lazy” ><!–
    <div>Any, html css img background, whatever. <img src=”some.png” /> </div>
–></pre>

<script type=”text/javascript” src=”jquery.lazyloader.js” ></script>
<script type=”text/javascript” >
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $(’pre.i-am-lazy’).lazyLoad();
});
</script>
```

So basically you wrap the content you want to lazy load with a placeholder tag and and inner HTML comment. When the placeholder becomes visible in the viewport, it is replaced with the HTML string inside the comment.

You can use any tag for the placeholder but I like pre because it renders as 0 dimension when there's only a comment inside.

Comment: yes your solution works but it is not acceptable because it is not unobtrusive, i.e. your solution will not work for browsers with js disabled - no images will be shown. As far as I know there is no way to prevent images being loaded (in new browsers) after document ready is triggered