# How do I hide images that are outside of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a site where new contents are automatically loading while scrolling (like a Facebook wall). Each content item has an image and it can have even 1000+ images on the same page. For performance I want to add `display:none` to images out of viewport. I can't separate the content to pages!

I have already written the script. It loads X new item when user reaches the bottom.

My problem is that after 60+ images the browser gets laggy.

Comment: `display:none` won't really help as the images will be loaded nonetheless. You should try to only load the images when a certain scroll-position is reached.

Comment: when you set the content that is not in the viewport to display:none then you will get another problem. It will never come in the viewport, because it is not rendered out and you can't scroll to it.

Comment: Are you sure, this will help? Browsers (at least, FF10) don't process elements out of viewport already.

Comment: Very similar (if not duplicate) of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371483/786814

Comment: Please see my comment yunzens answer. @sven: it's in a fixed height container so it won't affect

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you can just loop through the location of all your elements to determine if they are within the current viewport based off of scroll location.

The only problem is for each image you lave to loop through the DOM tree to determine its actual location and doing this for each image if you have 100+ images is going to consume more memory then leaving the 100+ sitting there.

I understand the concern but unless you are having actual performance issues from this I would leave it be.

Comment: I see. Well, you could set a property on the image container to determine its location when its created so you don't have to loop through the tree every time to lookup. Then just bind scroll and determine if the image containers top falls between scrollTop and scrollTop + window.offsetHeight. If it doesn't you can hide it. You'll need to find a way to detect when the user stops scrolling though rather than popping every time it scrolls.

Answer (score -1):

### edit1

Second try:
Here is a toggle functionality:
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/LzGGd
Mix this with my other fiddle

---

### HTML

```
<div data-tagname="img" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/2" data-width="300" data-height="200" style="width:300px; height: 200px">Click on it</div>
```

---

### jQuery

```
$(function() {

    $.fn.makeImg = function() {
        var img = $('<' + $(this).data('tagname') + ' class="toggle" src="' + $(this).data('src') + '" width="' + $(this).data('width') + '" height="' + $(this).data('height') + '">')
        $(this).replaceWith(img)
    }

    $.fn.makeDiv = function() {
        var div = $('<div data-tagname="img" data-src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" data-width="' + $(this).attr('width') + '" data-height="' + $(this).attr('height') + '" style="width:' + $(this).attr('width') + 'px; height:' + $(this).attr('height') + 'px;">')
        $(this).replaceWith(div)
    }

    $('img.toggle').live('click', function() {
        $(this).makeDiv()    
    })
    $('[data-tagname="img"]').live('click', function() {
        $(this).makeImg()

    })
})​
```

---

### original

If you do it like facebook (or twitter) you should inspect the scrollTop of your window with JavaScript.
If the scrollTop is let's say 200px less than the full window height minus body height, start a AJAX request that loads new HTML that is added after your current HTML. The images are not loaded before that.

Here ( http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/QhMe5/ , uses jQuery) you find a demonstration (without the AJAX part).
It appends to the body (some HTML) if you scroll down and have only 200 pixels to scroll left.

Comment: You don't understand me. For first page load it loads 20 images for example. If the user scrolls down it loads another 20. Scrolling down and another 20 again, and so on. So it will. My problem is that after 60 images the brwser gets laggy.

Comment: You cannot do it. `display: none` will not stop the image from loading. You could of course try to have the first 20 images be real images and then the others are divs with data attributes (data-src=[img src here] data-width=[image width hre] data-height=[image height here]). If they scroll into view, you could have jQuery transform the div in an image using the data

Comment: I DON'T WANT TO STOP LOADING THE IMAGE! Only want to hide already loaded images which are out of viewport. Which are already scrolled over by the user...

Comment: Hi! Can you share your solution using display:none? I need to use it for iOS app with uiwebview!

Answer (score -1):

If the images are loaded, they will have to be in the local client memory or cache anyway, taking resources, there is nothing you can do about it.

But if they are not shown at the moment, the browser is not rendering them anyway, so there is no kind of resource you can save by setting `display:none` to the images.

I assume you know you have to load the images on demand via Javascript, not at page initial load, otherwise your page would take forever to load.

Comment: It's not about the memory, it's about the laggyness. With 60+ images scrolling becomes laggy. Already tried with display: none, it's working perfectly.